# не удается вставить объект в массив по нужному индексу JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, length

По событию происходит выполнение кода следующего вида:

```
var arr=[];
var i = 'string';
arr[i]=[];
var k = arr[i].length;
arr[i][k] = [{
            text:SomeText
        }];
```

по идее, значение k должно каждый раз увеличиваться и присваивать объект с текстом на новый индекс (arr[i][0], arr[i][1], arr[i][2], ..), но k остается постоянным и из-за этого новые объекты не добавляются, а перезаписывают старый
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где может быть ошибка?

Comment: в данном коде никак k не может каждый раз увеличиваться, ибо написано один раз

Comment: не могу разобраться, тогда в чем разница между var k= arr.length;
       arr[k] = { text: SomeText } 
        и кодом выше?

Comment: Ключом массива может быть только целое число. Вы создаёте каждый раз новый массив, ничего в этом случае увеличиваться не будет!

Comment: вынесите инициализацию массива из функции - https://eval.in/928785

Comment: спасибо, вынес arr[i]=[]; за пределы функции и все сработало

Comment: @splash58, оформи как ответ

Comment: @Grundy на мой взгляд, такие вопросы надо просто удалять. Не представляю, как написать ответ, чтоб хоть кому-то потом это было полезно

Comment: @splash58, на самом деле довольно частый вопрос, когда инициализация переменных проходит внутри обработчика, и спрашивают почему значение не меняется. Можно в принципе поискать дубликат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы инициализируете массив при каждом вызове функции и, таким образом, теряете предыдущее значение. Достаточно вынести блок

```
var arr=[];
var i = 'string';
arr[i]=[];
```

а при вызове функции делать

```
arr[i].push({
            text:'SomeText'
        });
}
```

и всё будет работать